# Change the title attribute of summary if details is open

Tags: javascript, beginner, html5

I have this JavaScript code that functions as intended, although as a beginner, I do not know of a shorter, more efficient way of writing it.

The code is a simple toggle that changes the `title` attribute of the `<summary>` HTML tag from `hide` to `show` when the user clicks on the `<summary>` to open the `<details>`.

I used loops since there are several of these in my page:

```
var i,l;

var detailsElem = document.getElementsByTagName('details'),
summaryElem = document.getElementsByTagName('summary'),
summElemLen = summaryElem.length;
detlElemLen = detailsElem.length;

function detailsToggle() {
  for (i = 0; i < summElemLen; i++) {
    if (detailsElem[i].open === true) {
      summaryElem[i].title = 'hide';
    }
    else {
      summaryElem[i].title = 'show';
    }
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < detlElemLen; i++) {
  detailsElem[i].ontoggle = function() {detailsToggle()};
}
```

Is there a less verbose way of achieving the same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
detailsElem[i].ontoggle = function() {detailsToggle()};
```

It's better to use `addEventListener`. The problem is that doing it this way replaces anything assigned to `ontoggle`, potentially blowing away any handler put by other code.

```
var detailsElem = document.getElementsByTagName('details'),
summaryElem = document.getElementsByTagName('summary'),
summElemLen = summaryElem.length;
detlElemLen = detailsElem.length;
```

Personally recommending a `var` *per* variable. That way, you can easily add/remove lines without worrying about continuation. One such example is `summElemLen` ending with a `;` and not a `,`. This will cause `detlElemLen` to be defined on the global scope, and open to collision. This minor oversight can cause a lot of headache in the long term.

Also, using `getElementsByTagName` is very broad. Do you *really* want to take all elements? Or just a subset? If it's the latter, use a class name instead.

```
if (detailsElem[i].open === true) {
```

`if` statements expect a boolean. `detailsElem[i].open` is already a boolean. No need to do `=== true`, it's redundant. `true === true` is always a true.

Lastly, one flaw in the code is that once you toggle one detail element, you toggle all summary titles regardless of whether they belong to the element you clicked.

---

The following is what I consider shorter, more explicit and takes advantage of the array API. We get all detail elements, loop through and attach a handler. Handler checks if a summary is present and only sets a title if there is one.

```
const slice = Array.prototype.slice

// querySelectorAll to select elements using a CSS selector.
// It returns an array-like structure (indexed, has length, no array API)
// To take advantage of array APIs, we use slice to convert to array.
const details = slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.detail'))

// Use forEach to loop through each detail element found
details.forEach(detail => {

  // Add event handler when toggle is fired
  detail.addEventListener('toggle', event => {

    // Look for the summary with querySelector. It's like querySelectorAll
    // Except it returns either an element or null, instead of an array.
    const summary = detail.querySelector('summary')

    // No summary, do nothing.
    if(!summary) return;

    // Otherwise, assign title depending on detail state.
    summary.title = detail.open ? 'hide' : 'show'
  })
})
```

Comment: Why use `Array.slice`?  Would it not be more concise to use the spread operator? eg `const details = [...document.querySelectorAll(query)];`

Comment: @Blindman67 old habits.